# SalesForce.com - General advice for pulling data to external website

Tags: salesforce

We have a database driven website that pulls information in real-time from the same database our business uses to store CRM type information.   We are considering moving more and more of this CRM information into SalesForce instead of our own proprietary database.   I am looking into if and how we will be able to pull this data from SalesForce in real-time instead of our current database.   It seems like the Force.com REST API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm) might be the perfect solution for this, but I am concerned about the possibility we could surpass our Total API Request limit (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api.meta/api/implementation_considerations.htm?SearchType=Stem).

I believe our limit would be somewhere between 15,000 and 30,000 calls.  This seems like a large number, but our site is hit by 100’s of users per day, and the way the site is architected, it is very “chatty” with the database.   Each user might trigger dozens of database calls as they bounce around through the site.   I think there is a possibility that on busy days, we could exceed our API call limit.

My question is whether I am misunderstanding some basic concept.  This must be a common situation for companies using SalesForce in the architecture.  Is there some common strategy SalesForce advises for this problem?  Is the Force.com REST API the wrong tool for this job?   Is replication of data from SalesForce back down into our own database the general recommendation?   Replication is messy, so if there is any way we can avoid that, I’d like to explore any strategy that doesn’t involve replication first.

Answer (score 0):

Your limits on API calls are affected by the amount/type of licenses your org has, with a baseline of 15,000. The equation would look something like this:

15,000 + (number of licenses * call per license type).

REST API should accomplish what you're looking to do, provided you're within the call limits. You do have the option to "purchase" a higher API call limit.

Here's a reference article from the Salesforce Developer Documentation site:

[Salesforce API Request Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm)